# loading jar files during splash screen in javafx

Tags: javafx, splash-screen, jarsigner

I have an application which has refrences to 4 - 5 external jar (lib). But when i run my application on netbeans , netbeans first loads the jar file and after that my application scene appears. And I am trying to use the javafx preloader as well for splash screen. But preloader scene also loads after the jar files loading.
But I want to have loading of jars during my preloader scene is displaying i.e i want the loading of jars as a progress to my splash screen and then my main application scene should start. Pls help

My JNLP file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" xmlns:jfx="http://javafx.com" href="Black.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>Black</title>
    <vendor>RATTAN</vendor>
    <description>Sample JavaFX 2.0 application.</description>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <resources os="Windows">
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.0+" href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
  </resources>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
    <jar href="Black.jar" size="2407915" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar" size="253494" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-io-1.3.2.jar" size="95657" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/commons-lang-2.0.jar" size="179419" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/newlink.jar" size="6161" download="eager" />
    <jar href="lib/scribe-1.3.0.jar" size="74544" download="eager" />
  </resources>
<security>
  <all-permissions/>
</security>
  <applet-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="Black" />
  <jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600" main-class="test.Test"  name="Black" />
  <update check="always"/>
</jnlp>
```

I have used another preloader project which i have configured as preloader to my main project in netbeans

Comment: Please include the jnlp file in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the documentation on [Packaging an Application with a Preloader](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABJDJDJ).

Check your generated jnlp file, it should contain values something similar to this:

```
<resources>
  <j2se version="1.6+" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
  <jar href="lib/FirstPreloader.jar" size="2801" download="progress" />
  <jar href="AnimatedCircles.jar" size="13729" download="always" />
</resources>
<applet-desc  width="800" height="600"
    main-class="com.javafx.main.NoJavaFXFallback"  name="AnimatedCircles" />
<jfx:javafx-desc  width="800" height="600"
  main-class="animatedcircles.AnimatedCircles"  name="AnimatedCircles"  
  preloader-class="firstpreloader.FirstPreloader"/>
<update check="background"/>
```

Note some important tags `download="progress"` on the Preloader jar, `preloader-class` and `update check="background"`.

There is also a `download=lazy` value you can set on some dependent jars if you like (see the [jnlp spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html)).  Lazy download might not really be needed if you have a preloader, but it is defined as:

> This means the resource does not have to be downloaded onto the client system before the application is launched.

Note once update checks are switched on and lazy downloading is being used, it can be pretty difficult to accurately debug your application during development because on execution, the app may use cached versions of code rather the latest version of code.  So these kind of switches are best just used for final deployment.

Also read thread the [Performance Tips](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/preloaders.htm#BABIJCII) section of the JavaFX deployment guide.

Comment: but how to load jar files during splash screen of preloader for my main application